# Form submission returns inputs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a submission form, if a user submit the form it should redirect him to the next page which is in confirmation controller. So far it redirects back with the inputs like this 
`{"shipping_city":"gfg","shipping_phone":"087484","shipping_name":"Hellle",}`

Here is my code

CheckoutController

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item);
    $product = product::find($productId);
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
        'shipping_phone' => $request->phone,
         'shipping_name' => $request->name,
    ]);


    if ($order) {
        foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
           if (empty($item)) {
               continue;
           }
           $product = product::find($productId);
           OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
            'product_id' => $productId,
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
        ]);
       }
       return $order;
    }
    $cart = session()->remove('cart');
     return redirect()->route('confirmation.index');
   }
```

Checkout.blade

```
    <form action="{{ route('checkout.store') }}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
         <div class=shippingform>
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="half-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" required>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end half-form -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required>
            </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="complete-order" class="buttons-primary full-width">Complete Order</button>
    </form>
```

ConfirmationController

```
  public function index()
 {
    {
        if (! session()->has('success_message')) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return view('thankyou');
    }
 }
```

Routes

```
 Route::post('/checkout', 'CheckoutController@store')->name('checkout.store');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `if ($order) {
    ...
    return $order;
}
$cart = session()->remove('cart');
return redirect()->route('confirmation.index');`
This looks like you just mistakenly exchanged the cases: When you have found an order, you should redirect the user, not just return the input-values. Or am i missing something?

Comment: After the order I wanted to redirect the  user to the thank you page @TobiasF.

Comment: Then this is a simple error, have a closer look at when you are returning what in your code.

Comment: I didn't get that can you explain @TobiasF.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what your code currently does and what you want it to do:

Current Code with comments:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item);
    $product = product::find($productId);
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
        'shipping_phone' => $request->phone,
        'shipping_name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    if ($order) { // If a new order was successfully created
        foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
           // Do some stuff with each item / product
        }
        return $order; // return the newly created order with it's data
    }
    // If we didn't created a new order for whatever reason
    $cart = session()->remove('cart');
    return redirect()->route('confirmation.index'); // Redirect user to the "confirmation.index" route
}
```

As you can see, you just return the data of the created order (when $order is not false), otherwise you redirect to the "confirmation.index" page. Since this always does the opposite of what it should do (returning the order although you should be redirected to the confirmation page and vice versa), you have to swap the cases:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    ...
    if ($order) { // If a new order was successfully created
        foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
           // Do some stuff with each item / product
        }
        $cart = session()->remove('cart');
        return redirect()->route('confirmation.index'); // Redirect user to the "confirmation.index" route
    }
    // If we didn't created a new order for whatever reason
    return false; // return something else, since we didn't create an order
}
```

Comment: If I remove that `return $order` it redirects to the home page and also the order won't show in dashboard (only shows in database)@Tobias

Comment: I have tried to change my code with your code but it redirects to the home page after the order and not the (confirmation.index) @Tobias F.